# How to display excerpt post on hamepage and archive pages?

Tags: posts, archives, excerpt

I am showing full posts on my blog's homepage and also in archive pages but the problem is, Now i have posted some long post and i want to show there only excerpt with read more button on hamepage and archive page but only for specific posts. Who is it possible? Here is post link https://pak-poetry.com/lab-pe-aati-hai-dua-banke-tamanna-meri/

Comment: have you tried to use the 'more' tag https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More ? any coding solution depends on your currently used theme, consider asking at https://wordpress.org/support/theme/generatepress

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings> reading in your WordPress dashboard and change the setting from full text to summary.[image]